# Reading a csv file into PySpark that contains the key:value pairing, such that key becomes the column and value is the data of it

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner of Spark. Please help me out with a solution.

The csv file contains the text in the form of key:value paring delimited by a comma. And in some lines, the keys(or columns) may be missing.

I have loaded this file into a single column of a dataframe. I want to segregate these keys as columns and values associated to it as data into that column. And when there are some columns missing i want to add a new column and a dummy data to that.

Dataframe

```
 +----------------------------------------------------------------+
 |   _c0                                                          |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------+
 |name:Pradnya,IP:100.0.0.4, college: SDM, year:2018              |
 |name:Ram, IP:100.10.10.5, college: BVB, semester:IV, year:2018  |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want the output in this form

```
  +----------- ----------------------------------------------
  |  name     |  IP         | College   |  Semester | year  |
  +-----------+-------------------------+-----------+-------+
  |  Pradnya  |100.0.0.4    |  SDM      |  null     | 2018  |
  +-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
  |  Ram      | 100.10.10.5 | BVB       | IV        |2018   |
  +-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark won't recognize the key:value pairing. One workaround is convert the file int json format and then read the json file.
content of raw.txt:

```
name:Pradnya,IP:100.0.0.4, college: SDM, year:2018
name:Ram, IP:100.10.10.5, college: BVB, semester:IV, year:2018
```

Following code will create the json file :

```
with open('raw.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump([dict([p.split(':') for p in l.split(',')]) for l in open('raw.txt')], outfile)
```

Now you can create the pyspark dataframe using following code :

```
df = spark.read.format('json').load('raw.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all field names and keys/values do not contain embedded delimiters. then you can probably convert the key/value lines into Row object through RDD's map function.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from string import lower

# assumed you already defined SparkSession named `spark`
sc = spark.sparkContext

# initialize the RDD
rdd = sc.textFile("key-value-file")

# define a list of all field names
columns = ['name', 'IP', 'College', 'Semester', 'year']

# set Row object
def setRow(x):
    # convert line into key/value tuples. strip spaces and lowercase the `k`
    z = dict((lower(k.strip()), v.strip()) for e in x.split(',') for k,v in [ e.split(':') ])
    # make sure all columns shown in the Row object
    return Row(**dict((c, z[c] if c in z else None) for c in map(lower, columns)))

# map lines to Row objects and then convert the result to dataframe
rdd.map(setRow).toDF().show()
#+-------+-----------+-------+--------+----+
#|college|         ip|   name|semester|year|
#+-------+-----------+-------+--------+----+
#|    SDM|  100.0.0.4|Pradnya|    null|2018|
#|    BVB|100.10.10.5|    Ram|      IV|2018|
#+-------+-----------+-------+--------+----+
```